# Jquery is not accepting hypen in the jsp page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a field sent by SERVICE which is having hypen in it. Eg., **first-name** (As JSON object)

But when I try to get the value of that field through the jsp. I am getting a script error.

Please let me know how to access the hypen also in this?

var nameList = msg.RESPONSE.DATA.NAME-LIST;

The above way when I try to access it is throwing script error

Comment: How you are trying to access it?

Comment: please share your code that you have tried.

Comment: var nameList = msg.RESPONSE.DATA.NAME-LIST;

Comment: THe above way when I try to access it is throwing script error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable or property name with an hyphen is indeed wrong in javascript (Jquery).

However, you can access the "problematic" property like this :

```
var nameList = msg.RESPONSE.DATA["NAME-LIST"];
```

I would recommend to rename the property(ies) 
without hyphen if you control the content of this response